# querying collection group in firestore

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I have just started using firestore and I have a question on how to query the data.

I have a record structure like this

```
{
"idName": "aquarobur",
"displayName": "Aqua Robur Technologies",
"categories": {
 "orgtype": [ "private"],
  "sdg": [ "11","17"],
  "segment": [ "building-and-construction", "consulting"]
 }
}
```

I want to filter / query on the "categories" values. 
Eg:  get all records that has “segment” and  "building-and-construction"

```
const snapshot = catalog_entryRef.where('categories.segment', '==', 'building-and-construction').get()
```

I have tried this. But it does not return any records. 
It seems to me that I can only query fields that are the first level of the record. Eg I can query using "idName" like this

```
const snapshot = catalog_entryRef.where('idName', '==', ‘aquarobur’).get()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `==` in a query does an equality check. So it only returns documents where the field has the complete, exact value that you specify.

You need an `array-contains` operation for what you want:

```
catalog_entryRef.where('categories.segment', 'array-contains', 'building-and-construction').get()
```

For more information, see the Firebase documentation on [array membership](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership).